# What is correct path in .js file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, filepath

I have a js script which plays a video on my home page and I can't get the correct path to the video folder in this script. It only works in an html static project.

*assets/javascript/common.js*

```
var videobackground = new $.backgroundVideo($('#background-video'), {

  "path": "/video/"

});
```

*assets/javascript/video/* - my videos in this folder

---

---

I tried sending the `root_path` variable in my application file, but it doesn't work either.

*application.html.haml*

```
:javascript

  var ROOT_URL = '#{Rails.root}';
```

---

*application.html.haml*

```
var videobackground = new $.backgroundVideo($('#background-video'), {

  "path": ROOT_URL + "/app/assets/javascripts/video/"

});
```

Comment: `Rails.root` returns the actual path of your app's folder (on Ubuntu, something like `/home/user_name/your_rails_app`).

Comment: Yes, I know. I tried both methods and they don't work.

Comment: Have you tried putting your videos in `/public/...`? You shouldn't put large files like videos in the asset pipeline.

Comment: Agree with Beartech, put it in a video directory in public, so http://www.siteurl/public/video/

Comment: Do not use _ROOT_URL_ in your views, especially as href or src for some resource. All your requests go through Rails routes or directly (in production) to the file that is (usually) in your public dir. So the request path and the absolute path of file at hard drive is not same

Comment: "path": "http://localhost:3000/public/video/" still doesn't work for me

Comment: don't add localhost, try with public/videos

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if you really want than i assets, try putting that video in `app/assets/videos` and then in the `config/application.rb` do

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/videos"
config.assets.enabled = true
```

else put it in `public/videos` then, your `video_tag "video.mp4"` should automatically loaf from there

Comment: I need write path to folder with my videos in js file which locates in assets and I don't know what is correct path. 

video_tag - for views, not js